# Error when logging in using yahoo openid

Tags: javascript, node.js

[Errors.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blmMN.jpg)

Basically, I am trying to login with yahoo openid and I really don't understand what these errors mean. any pointers/ help needed. I am stuck on this for quite some time now. 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put the errors in plain text with the question?

Also include what code caused the errors.

Comment: Is the URL you are trying to authenticate against a valid openid endpoint?

Comment: Basically there is this framework known as webinos that I am trying to use. I have done the npm install and when i run it with the node command it asks for a login to the host. I have created yahoo openid. when i login it gives me these errors. I can/t comprehend what these errors mean. Is it because I haven't provided the clientid, callback urls etc ?